# Location of minimum in Julia

Tags: julia

Does Julia have a build in command to find the index of the minimum of a vector?  R, for example, has a `which.min` command (and a `which.max`, of course).

Obviously, I could write the following myself, but it would be nice not to have to.

```
function whichmin( x::Vector )
  i = 1
  min_x=minimum(x)
  while( x[i] > min_x ) 
    i+=1 
  end
  return i
end
```

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Comment: You want **max** or **min**? Your question title says, **min**, but the answers are **max**. :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since 0.7-alpha, `indmin` and `indmax` are deprecated.
Use [`argmin`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.argmin) and [`argmax`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.argmax) instead.

For a vector it just returns the linear index

```
julia> x = rand(1:9, 4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 9
 5
 8
 5

julia> argmin(x)
2

julia> argmax(x)
1
```

If looking for both the index and the value, use [`findmin`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.findmin) and [`findmax`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.findmax).

For multidimensional array, all these functions return the CartesianIndex.

Comment: Finally! It is much more reasonable. The `ind2sub` answer was really annoying.

Answer (score 9):

I believe `indmax(itr)` does what you want. From the julia [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/):

> **indmax(itr) → Integer**
>
> > Returns the index of the maximum element in a collection.

And here's an example of it in use:

```
julia> x = [8, -4, 3.5]
julia> indmax(x)
1
```

Comment: @squipbar to help others, please note that this solution is no longer current as of Julia v1.0, should tick another solution.

Comment: yep, for julia >= 1 use `argmax()` instead of `indmax()`

Answer (score 9):

There's also findmax, that returns both the maximum value and its position.

Comment: For a 2D array, `findmax` returns one integer instead of the 2D location

Comment: @pushpen.paul do you know how to find the original-D location, then?

Answer (score 1):

For multidim array, you'll have to switch between linear indexes et multidim indexes:

```
x = rand(1:9, 2,3)
# 2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
#  5  1  9
#  3  3  8

indmin(x)
# 3 
# => third element in the column-major ordered array (value=1)

ind2sub(size(x),indmin(x))
# (1, 2)
# => (row,col) indexes: what you are looking for.
```

-- Maurice